# Power series of $\frac{x+1}{x^2+5}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series

I have this problem: write down the power series of $$\frac{x+1}{x^2+5}$$ and specify for which interval the equality (function = series) holds true.

I noticed that I can use differentiation method here.

So I started by writing down:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\arctan \frac{x}{\sqrt{5}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{-1}{5}\right)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \tag{1}$$

This is known since the power series of $\arctan{u}$ is known.
This equality holds true for $|x| \le \sqrt{5}$ (this I know from theory).

Differentiating (1) gives me:

$$\frac{1}{x^2+5} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{-1}{5}\right)^n x^{2n}\tag{2}$$

Multiplying this by $x$ gives me:

$$\frac{x}{x^2+5} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{-1}{5}\right)^n x^{2n+1}\tag{3}$$

Now I need to sum up (2) and (3). I get this somewhat strangely written series:

$$\frac{x+1}{x^2+5} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{-1}{5}\right)^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor} x^n \tag{4}$$

I say strangely written because I use $\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor$ here.

OK, now I know (4) holds true for sure in $(-\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{5})$ (since (2) and (3) have the same radius of convergence as (1)).

Finally, I think that for $x = \pm\sqrt{5}$ equality (4) does not hold true, because if we look at the terms with e.g. odd indices in (4) they are $1/5, -1/5, 1/5, -1/5, ...$ So the sub-sequence of these terms doesn't go to zero. So there's no way (4) can be convergent for $x = \pm\sqrt{5}$. Right?

I hope I didn't miscalculate somewhere but I think I didn't.

My questions are:

1. Is (4) correct? And is there a simpler way to write down (4) without $\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor$? WolframAlpha doesn't help me much for this:

[WA power series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2B1%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B5%29%20maclaurin%20series)

I mean, it seems it doesn't provide clear expression for $a_n$ as I do in (4).

2. Is my conclusion for $x=\pm\sqrt{5}$ correct? I mean, that the series (4) diverges there.
3. And also in general... did I make any mistake at any step here?

Comment: from wikipedia: the fact that the radius of convergence is always the distance from the center a to the nearest singularity; also to expand your function you can use the geometric series instead of using the derivative of the arctan

Comment: Maybe a simpler way is to use $$\frac1{1+y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-y)^n$$
which has radius $1$,
then (with $y:=\frac{x^2}5$)
$$\frac1{x^2+5}=\frac15\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{x^2}5}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac15\left(-\frac15\right)^nx^{2n},$$
which has radius $\sqrt5$ because $|y|<1\iff|x|<\sqrt5$. Since $x+1$ has infinite radius (!), the product of both series will have radius $\min(\infty,\sqrt5)=\sqrt5$.

Comment: Both assertions are correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry... which assertions? You mean... there's no mistake in my solution? All conclusions are good?

Comment: Yes. I was talking about assertion $(4)$ and the fact that you made no mistake.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos OK... Well, thanks. Any simpler way to write (4) without using $\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor$? I guess that's the only question left then.

Comment: I would leave it like that.

Comment: You could make it more compact as $$\frac 15 \sum_{n=0}^\infty  5^{-n/2} \left(\sqrt{5} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi 
   n}{2}\right)\right)x^n $$

Answer (score 2):

From the geometric series,$$\frac1{x^2+5}=\frac15\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{x^2}5\right)^k$$ so that

$$\frac{x+1}{x^2+5}=\frac15\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}+x^{2k+1}}{5^k}.$$

You can indeed replace the even/odd exponents $2k$ and $2k+1$ by a single sum on the integer $n$, and that makes $k=\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$, generating the duplicated sequence $0,0,1,1,2,2,\cdots$